# Resque filling up Redis database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, resque

I've inherited a Rails project hosted on Heroku which uses Resque for background tasks.  Right now the application has only about 100 active users, and I've been notified that the Redis database is at 80% of the 100mb capacity.

I didn't set any of this up, and I only have a cursory understanding that Redis is used by Resque in queueing background jobs, so I'm struggling to get my head around a) if this is a problem/ outside of the norm and b) if so what avenues do I have to get in and figure out what is the problem.

Any incite would be much appreciated!

Comment: did you get this solved?

Comment: still figuring it out.  I ran that command and it looks like everything is in order as far as workers - I zeroed out the redis DB and I'm monitoring it to see if I can figure out what is actually piling up.

Answer (score 1):

Check if there are running resque workers with

```
$ heroku ps -a<app id>
```

Maybe there are no workers running to clean the queue.

Other than that, 100Mb isn't all that much. If the jobs that are being enqueued have long params list or big hashes, that could fill up pretty quickly.

Another thing to look for is if jobs are enqueued during user updates that, due to user behavior, might enqueue a lot of duplicated jobs. In this case, making jobs unique with [loner](https://github.com/resque/resque-loner) might help you out.